# What's the difference between /etc/rc.d/rc*.d and /etc/rc*.d

Tags: directory-structure, init-script, architecture, sysvinit, init.d

I know that rc*.d directories are used at startup, or reboot, or so on time, for starting or stopping programs. Can anybody explain me what's the difference between the rc*.d folders placed under the `/etc/` path and the other placed under the `/etc/rc.d/` path.

Also, what's the difference between `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/rc.d/init.d`?

Thanks.

N.B. I'm running CentOS 6.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing.  Different Linux distributions, and the LSB, had different standards, so both are present on CentOS to make it easier to run software from different versions.  One is just a symbolic link to the other.

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Installation_Guide/s2-boot-init-shutdown-init.html gives details on the boot process, but ultimately all the init scripts are almost-but-not-completely identical on the different Linux systems.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same! `/etc/init.d` is a symbolic link of `/etc/rc.d/init.d`.