# Purpose and typical usage of /etc/rc.local

Tags: debian, configuration, startup

The header looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local - executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel
#
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
```

What is the reason for this file (it does not contain much), and what commands do you usually put in it? What is a "multiuser runlevel"? (I guess `rc` is "run commands"?)

Comment: I don't know if this is the "official" purpose of the file, but I found out that I can use the file for what should happen on startup, and would require super user access, but **without** having to provide the password. That would typically involve colors, the keyboard, and other such stuff. Check out some examples [here](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/conf/rc.local).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

A [runlevel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel) is a state of the system, indicating whether it is in the process of booting or rebooting or shutting down, or in single-user mode, or running normally. The traditional [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) program handles these actions by switching to the corresponding runlevel. Under Linux, the runlevels [are by convention](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/runlevels.html):

- S while booting,
- 0 while shutting down,
- 6 while rebooting,
- 1 in single-user mode and
- 2 through 5 in normal operation.

Runlevels 2 through 5 are known as multiuser runlevels since they allow multiple users to log in, unlike runlevel 1 which is intended for only the system administrator.

When the runlevel changes, init runs [rc scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30728/whats-the-difference-between-etc-rc-d-rc-d-and-etc-rc-d) (on systems with a traditional init — there are alternatives, such as [Upstart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) and [Systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd)). These rc scripts typically start and stop system services, and are provided by the distribution.

The script `/etc/rc.local` is for use by the system administrator. It is traditionally executed after all the normal system services are started, at the end of the process of switching to a multiuser runlevel. You might use it to start a custom service, for example a server that's installed in `/usr/local`. Most installations don't need `/etc/rc.local`, it's provided for the minority of cases where it's needed.

Comment: I found out today that on current FreeBSD, rc.local may get executed pretty early. Definitely not after all normal system services are started. I wanted a beep when sshd access to a headless machine would become available, and `rc.local` wasn't suitable for this reason. Since the original question is about Debian, this comment is probably irrelevant for the OP.

Comment: @MvG Thanks for the information. `rc.local` was traditionally run last, but I see that FreeBSD stopped doing that when they switched to a dependency-based system. Mind you, even if `rc.local` was invoked after `/etc/rc.d/sshd`, that wouldn't work perfectly: `rc.local` would be invoked soon after the `sshd` process was started, it could be invoked before `sshd` had started to listen to the network (but we'd be talking tenths of a second at most in a typical setup).

Comment: I'm trying to use it to set up network for lxc containers and auto start them. But it stops after `iptables-apply /root/iptables`. I'm in the process of figuring out what's wrong (waiting for next reboot). But if you've got any suggestions, I'm all ears.

Comment: @x-yuri This requires way more information than what you posted here. I don't even know what “it” is in “it stops”. Ask a new question that explains what you did.

Answer (score 17):

`rc` denotes "run-control",

The `multiuser` runlevel would be defined as the level at which networking is available and thus connections to the server could be made using those services in lieu of hard-wired console connections.

Mind you, servers are generally managed by a service processor (under various names) which do support network connections and in turn act as if you indeed had a hard-wired console.

As for the `rc.local` file, this is a convenience to allow you to specify all of the "local" (site-specific) objects (daemons and/or once-at-boot scripts) you want to start.  You may choose to use this paradigm or actually populate '/etc/init.d' with start/stop scripts, appropriately.

Comment: Okay, but why is the file there, and when do you typically use it, and how (for example, what commands make sense to put in it)?

Answer (score 6):

The `rc.local` file on *Debian* is mostly for compatibility with non-init style systems. You should not use it.

Instead, it is recommended that you copy `/etc/init.d/Skeleton` to a new init script for whatever you want to happen while changing runlevels, then use `inserv` to enable it.

---

Update: As per the comment below, this answer is no longer recommended. However, this answer was posted *several years* before skeleton deprecation, and that skeleton *still exists* in Debian unstable as of January 2019.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480897/5132 `/etc/init.d/skeleton` is not the way.

Answer (score 4):

I mainly use it for two things:

1. to log the date and kernel version of every reboot.  a simple one-liner that can easily be added to systems without any stuffing around...and far less prone to the boot history being corrupted than running `uptimed`.
2. to revive the old /etc/rc.boot/ directory that used to be in debian up until a few years ago.  I still have some simple scripts in there that aren't worth the effort of rewriting as an init.d script (e.g. a Q&D script to mail dmesg to root, and another one to use hdaparm to disable idle spindown and blockdev to set read-ahead size), and I'm happy for them to be run after all other boot-time scripts.

e.g.

```
echo "$(date +%s),$(date),$(uname -a)"  >> /var/log/reboot.log

[ -d /etc/rc.boot ] && run-parts /etc/rc.boot
```

Also, I wrote /etc/rc.local scripts earlier this year for centos and debian distros to get the ec2-style metadata from openstack (on `http://169.254.169.254/`) so that VMs would get their IP, hostname, ssh keys, and other instance-specific information.  cloud-init has since been ported to these distros, so the scripts are obsolete now.