# rc.local can't find my script

Tags: scripting, startup

I am trying to get my script to run on startup. I am using Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Here are the exact contents of /etc/r.local.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
sleep 1

/home/myusername/myscript.sh 15 &
exit 0
```

Here's relevant output from /var/log/syslog, when starting up:

```
rc.local[1157]: /etc/rc.local: 15: /etc/rc.local: /home/myusername/myscript.sh: not found
```

The script in question has all needed permissions AFAICT.

```
myusername@myserver:~$ ls -l /home/myusername/myscript.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 199 Jan 23 09:19 /myusername/myscript.sh
```

When manually executing rc.local or my script, it runs fine.

What could be some reasons that rc.local can't access the file on startup?

Comment: the sh-bang line of /home/myusername/myscript.sh is suspect; can you post it?

Comment: Is `/home` mounted at boot-time when `rc.local` is executing?

Comment: If by sh-bang line you mean the first line, this is it: `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: How do I determine when `/home` is mounted?

Comment: Did you by any chance write the script on a Windows system (so that it's a DOS text file)? If so, the `#! ` line would definitely point to a nonexistent interpreter, due to the extra carriage return character at the end of each line.

Comment: Move the script to `/usr/local/bin`. It's available earlier in the system startup process. To see how your system starts, page through `sudo journalctl  -b 0`

Answer (score 1):

If you've got rights to change `rc.local` you're also able to place your script into `/usr/local/bin`, or `/usr/bin`, or even `/bin` if necessary, which are more likely to be available at boot time than `/home`, which may be located on a different drive or partition.

Also read [more about the usage of `rc.local`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49626/purpose-and-typical-usage-of-etc-rc-local) to make sure it's the right place to do [what you intend](http://xyproblem.info). And be careful of *what* you do in that script, as it may mess up your boot process.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` did not work. Same problem, rc.local can't find the file.

Comment: Also, I'm just trying to get a simple script to run on startup and it seemed that using rc.local was the simplest way to do so. I was in fact following the directions of a guide.