# What's the difference between /etc/rc.local and /etc/init.d/rc.local?

Tags: configuration, startup

I want to add a permanent `iptables` rule to my new `VPS`, and after brief google search i was surprised that there are two places this rule can be added, that seems like identical: `/etc/rc.local` and `/etc/init.d/rc.local`. Maybe someone knows why where is two places for simple startup code to place? Is it linux flavor specific (but ubuntu has both!)? Or one of them is deprecated?

Comment: One should be a symlink to the other.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams On Ubuntu Server 12.04 x86 LTS they are completely different :(.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: On Debian they seem to be different as well.

Comment: Worth checking out: I asked a [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49626/purpose-and-typical-usage-of-etc-rc-local) about `/etc/rc.local` a while back.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between /etc/rc.d/rc\*.d and /etc/rc\*.d](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30728/whats-the-difference-between-etc-rc-d-rc-d-and-etc-rc-d)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Perhaps you wanted to say that `/etc/rc.local` is a symlink of `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`/etc/init.d` is maintained on ubuntu for backward compatibility with sysvinit stuff.  If you actually look at `/etc/init.d/rc.local` you'll see (also from a 12.04 LTS Server):

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFORMATION
# Provides:          rc.local
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Run /etc/rc.local if it exist
### END INIT INFO
```

And **"Run /etc/rc.local"** is exactly what it does.  The entirety of `/etc/rc.local` is:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exit 0
```

I would guess the purpose in doing this is to provide a dead simple place to put shell commands you want run at boot, without having to deal with the stop|start service stuff, which is in `/etc/init.d/rc.local`.

So it is in fact a service, and can be run as such.  I added a `echo` line to `/etc/rc.local` and:

```
»service rc.local start
hello world
```

However, I do not believe it is referenced by anything in upstart's `/etc/init` (not init.d!) directory:

```
»initctl start rc.local
initctl: Unknown job: rc.local
```

There are a few "rc" services in upstart:

```
»initctl list | grep rc
rc stop/waiting
rcS stop/waiting
rc-sysinit stop/waiting
```

But none of those seem to have anything to do with rc.local.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a distribution specific thing. (like, you will not find different rc.local in CentOS).

Now coming to your actual question, I think adding anything inside /etc/init.d/rc.local makes it to start as a "service" whereas, anything inside /etc/rc.local would simply launch that script at boot time.

I am not really sure on why Ubuntu still maintains both of them? (Perhaps someone else might shed some light over this part !!)

Comment: What is the difference between command that is executed "as a service" and a code that is "simply launched at boot time"? Is it some security or what?

Comment: The core difference between the two is essentially of a Service and a process. ;)

I guess the basic intent would be security only. You might find this link interesting: http://www.unixmen.com/managing-your-services-and-processes-in-linux/

Comment: This is incorrect!  They are not the same script, but they **are** one service -- `/etc/init.d/rc.local` does the stop start stuff on `/etc/rc.local` (see my answer for more details).

Comment: @goldilocks: Thanks for a very descriptive and thorough answer but I am not clear which part of my answer you referred to be incorrect? Saying one as a service means it can do the "start" and "stop" stuff, while the other as simply a process.
Please correct me if I am making no sense here.

Comment: @pragmatic Because the `/etc/rc.local` script is the executable process governed by the `/etc/initd/rc.local` script, just like (eg) `/bin/syslog` would be the executable process governed by `/etc/initd/syslog`.  You say explicitly that `/etc/rc.local` is just a boot script, vs. `/etc/initd/rc.local` being a completely separate run level service.